# What's the best way to display reply threads?

Tags: website-design, comments

I have a post and reply system. Currently when you view a post, you can see a list of its direct replies in a vertical scroller. You then click on a reply to see replies to that. I might call this "breadth" display. However, I have some users complaining that they'd prefer to follow comment threads through replies, i.e. "depth" display. The issue I have is, reply chains follow a tree structure, and it is not easy to decide how to show all these threads at the same time.

My question is: Is there a good or recommended way to display a comment tree? There are similar solutions online, such as Reddit's way of rendering, but most people I've talked to don't find that very intuitive either.

Answer (score 3):

There's a useful overview, including pros-and-cons, of various types of conversation threading here;

http://www.elezea.com/2015/09/how-to-display-threaded-discussions-on-the-web/

which might be useful. Based on the research done, the decision was made to use the `Teased, Capped, Threaded` format;

[image: teased, capped, threaded message format]

Hope this helps :)